# How to get Thread names into log instead of [p: default-threadpool; w: Idle]

Tags: java, log4j, threadpool

How can i print different thread name instead of

```
p: default-threadpool; w: Idle
```

I am using log4j  with

```
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] %x (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

But using this i am able to see only

```
p: default-threadpool; w: Idle
```

so it is difficult to identify which thread is doing what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2201209?tstart=0), `[p: default-threadpool; w: Idle]`, *is* the name of an RMI thread in your application. The `%t` you have in your conversion pattern is correct and is the one that causes log4j to print the thread name.